# Prove the function in the following symbolic dynamics problem can have any period

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems

I encountered this problem in my assignment.

$S: [0,1]\to [0,1] $

$$
S(x_n)=\begin{cases}
3x_n&0\leq x_n<\dfrac{1}{4}\\
x_n+\dfrac{1}{2}&\dfrac{1}{4}\leq x_n<\dfrac{1}{2}\\
3-4x_n&x_n\in[\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4})\\
2x_n-3/2&x_n\in[\dfrac{3}{4},1)
\end{cases}
$$
Show it has periodic points of all periods, or disprove this.

I have written out the shift patterns:

Let $\displaystyle x=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\dfrac{a_n}{2^n}$, where $a_n\in\{0,1\}$, then

1. If $a_1=a_2=0$, then $x\in[0,\dfrac{1}{4}]$, therefore
   $$
      S(x)=S[0,0,a_3,a_4,\cdots]=[0,a_3,a_4+a_3,a_5+a_4,\cdots]
      $$
2. If $a_1=0,a_2=1$, then $x\in[\dfrac{1}{4},\dfrac{1}{2}]$, therefore
   $$
      S(x)=S[0,1,a_3,a_4,\cdots]=[1,1,a_3,a_4,\cdots]
      $$
3. If $a_1=1,a_2=0$, then $x\in[\dfrac{1}{2},\dfrac{3}{4}]$, therefore
   $$
      S(x)=S[1,0,a_3,\cdots]=[1-a_3,1-a_4,\cdots]
      $$
4. If $a_1=1,a_2=1$, then $x\in[\dfrac{3}{4},1]$, therefore
   $$
      S(x)=S[1,1,a_3,a_4,\cdots]=[0,a_3,a_4,a_5,\cdots]
      $$

The fixed points of $S(x)$ are $x_0=\bar 0$, $x_1=\dfrac{3}{5}={0.1\overline{0011}}$. 2 period point $x_2=\overline{10}$.

But for period larger than $3$, I cannot find a point of that period, could someone tell me how to proceed?